# How can I keep the flash continuously on while taking a picture using the CameraX API?

Tags: android, camera

I am using the CameraX library to take pictures in my Android app, but I would like to keep the flash continuously on while the picture is being taken. I've tried using the `setFlashMode(FlashMode.ON)` method of the `ImageCapture` class, but the flash only fires for a moment during the capture. There does not seem to be a flash mode setting available like `FlashMode.TORCH` or `FLASH_TYPE_USE_TORCH_AS_FLASH` that would allow for keeping the flash continuously on. Is there a way to achieve this using the CameraX API?

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd add a button to turn on the torch and use that instead. Just before taking the picture, I automatically turn it off and use the normal flash. This works because my goal is to enable users to illuminate a target in a dark place before taking the picture.

> ```
>   camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle( ... );
>   if (camera.getCameraInfo().hasFlashUnit()) {
>       camera.getCameraControl().enableTorch(true);
>   }
> ```